# React ref appendChild is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I got this component with a ref that I copied 100% from a plugin (where it worked). The code creates a ref using the `React.createRef` method and then inserts a node into that ref. The exact same code works if I import the plugin but it doesn't work if I try to write it myself:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {EditorState} from 'prosemirror-state';
import {EditorView} from 'prosemirror-view';
import {options} from '@aeaton/react-prosemirror-config-default';


interface CodeEditorProps {
    attributes?: any;
    nodeViews?: any;
}

export default class CodeEditor extends React.Component<CodeEditorProps, void> {
    editorRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    view: EditorView;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.editorRef = React.createRef();

        this.view = new EditorView(null);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const node = this.editorRef.current;

        // ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: node.appendChild is not a function
        node.appendChild(this.view.dom);
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.editorRef}/>;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have some view with editorRef set  in render function ?

Comment: yes, code updated

Comment: Do you use React 16.3 or later?

Comment: yes I use `16.9.0`

Comment: Can you console log   this.editorRef before appendChild

Comment: ```_class
cmp: constructor {items: null, _items: null, innerItems: null, onItemAdd: null, lastSize: null, …}
props: {children: "adsads"}
xtype: "html"
htmltype: (...)
__proto__: htmlComponent```

Comment: it's Example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ref-example-lp9p1
to solve your problem i need the example similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `editorRef`, but it's not pointing to any HTML node as you are not setting it anywhere.

You would need to do something like `<div ref={this.editorRef} />` inside the `render()` function.

Alternatively, you could use  the Editor from `'@aeaton/react-prosemirror'` as you are already importing some part of it, as shown in [this demo](https://react-prosemirror-example.now.sh/), with the [source code here](https://github.com/hubgit/react-prosemirror/blob/master/react-prosemirror-example/src/index.js).

Comment: Yeah I have the render method inside there, I just omitted putting it to have a slimmer example. I son't want to use their package because it wraps a `div` that I can't control (make absolutely positioned)